# swift 3 error : Argument labels '(count:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

It is saying there is an overload error, though i am not sure why it is saying this...

```
   let value: UInt8 = 75
    let sendData = (bytes: [value])
    let data = Data(sendData: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(sendData), count: sendData.count)
    mainPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
```

I am looking to send the value of 75 via the writeValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swift 3, `Data` does conform to protocol `Sequence`, so the `count` argument is not needed anymore:

```
let value: UInt8 = 75
let data = Data([value])
mainPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
```

In previous versions of **Swift**, the `count` parameter was need in order to loop through the `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 it's much simpler because `Data` conforms to `Sequence`

```
let value : UInt8 = 75
let data = Data([value])
mainPeripheral!.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message means that the Data class does not have any func with the signature : init(sendData : UnsafePointer, count : Int). If you do not have a custom init for the Data class, this is expected behavior.